# Athena Partitioning limitation and how to best approach the problem I am describing

Tags: amazon-web-services, partitioning, amazon-athena, bucket

So here is what is happening

- I have a lambda function which reads a file of certain size and pushed to a server(This is the limitation as the server has limited TPS)
- The Lambda function therefore cannot read a large file on S3
- I am doing a CTAS (I am calculating the size for buckets). So, for example if I have 140M records **S** and If I need n recoreds in a file of size **s**, my bucket count is **S/s**
- However Athena complains that it cannot do more than 100 partitions(Its confusing since I am doing bucketing and not partitioning), but my bucket count comes to the count of 75K.

How do I handle this situation? Something I can think of is

- Have a Spark job which does repartitioning again.
- Manipulate Glue to somehow allow more than 100 partitions

Both approaches dont appeal to me. There must ne a simpler way.

Comment: What are you trying to do? why create that many buckets? Limitation are usually hints to best practices.

Answer (score 0):

ctas are limited to writing at most 100 partitions. You need to split your query into a first ctas writing up to 100 queries followed by `insert` queries also writing up to 100 partitions. An alternative approach though, is to create the table directly on glue and just do insert queries (always writing at most 100 partitions).

Doc here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-insert-into.html

Comment: the "partition" limitation is for both partitions and buckets (you can't write more than 100 total buckets or partitions). Error messages aren't always as clear as one would hope